# Html5 video and embed tag and Plugins issue

Tags: html, plugins, browser

I have written the following html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Presentation on HTML5</title>
<center>Contents</center>
</head>
<body>
<embed src="v1.mp4" height="240" width="320"/> 
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="v1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="v1.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="v1.webm" type="video/webm" />
 </video>
 <object data="v1.mp4" height="240" width="320"/>
</body>
</html>
```

As u see,I have used embed,object and video tag together to run a media element. When I disable the plug-ins in both chrome and firefox browser and run this code,all the videos run inspite of the fact that embed tag requires plug-ins to run a media element. Can anyone explain why chrome is still running video for embed tag though plug-ins are disabled?

Comment: can someone pls give me a response soon. i have a presentation on html5 and i am stuck with this video tag

Comment: This is very good question. I have been trying to do the same. Even after disabling all the plugin, I am still able to view the video even using the embed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with chrome. For your ppt use firefox. In firefox the video does not run after the plugin is disabled(with embed tag). But the same video can be run using the video tag of html5.

Answer (score 0):

Embed tag is not supported in google chrome. 
Check this link where even google accepts the problem with plug-in
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=15745

If u had used prev versions of IE you can easily the difference between these two tags.

use opera/ old ie in ur ppt to show the diff.